# Send file Via Boost ASIO TCP, how to stream char array to socket?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to convert .NET code to C++, I am very new to C++. Below is my .NET code. The main parts that I'm having trouble converting are reading the file into the correct byte array, taking the length and then streaming to the socket.

```
                Dim bmp As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(strImagePath)
                Dim client As New TcpClient("192.168.1.13", 10555)
                Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
                Dim lenbuffer As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(bmp.Length)
                stream.Write(lenbuffer, 0, lenbuffer.Length)
                stream.Write(bmp, 0, bmp.Length)
                stream.Flush()

                Dim response As Byte() = New Byte(9999) {}
                Dim totalread As Integer = 0
                Dim read As Integer = 1
                While read <> 0
                    read = stream.Read(response, 0, response.Length - totalread)
                    totalread += read
                End While


                strAnswer = encoding.ASCII.GetString(response, 0, totalread)
```

With the below C++ code I am confused as to how I should stream the char array to the socket.

```
char* readFileBytes(const char *name)
{
ifstream fl(name);
fl.seekg( 0, ios::end );
size_t len = fl.tellg();
char *ret = new char[len];
fl.seekg(0, ios::beg);
fl.read(ret, len);
 fl.close();
 return ret;
}

void SendImage(std::string strImageFile)
{

strImageFile = "/tmagent/images/1.gif";


char* FileData = readFileBytes(strImageFile.c_str());

boost::system::error_code ec;


boost::asio::io_service io_service;

boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("192.168.1.13", "10555");
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator end;

boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);

boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);


boost::asio::streambuf request;
std::ostream requestStream(&request);


//What do I do here to stream the file data?


boost::asio::write(socket, request);

boost::asio::streambuf respond;

boost::asio::read(socket, respond, completion, ec);

std::string strOutput;

strOutput = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(respond.data());
respond.consume(strOutput.size());
cout << "START OUTPUT: " << strOutput << "\n";
```

}

Comment: Just a quick-view: in function **readFileBytes** you are putting binary data into `char*` without specifying length. This will lead to trouble.

Comment: Avoid using naked `char *` for memory allocation. Prefer `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Asio has a bunch of overloaded [`buffer()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) functions that adapt various data containers to a [`ConstBufferSequence`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html) concept model, which is accepted by [`write`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write.html) function.

So you don't even have to use `streambuf`, just send the data straightforwardly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

vector<char> readFileBytes(const string &name)
{
  using namespace std;
  ifstream fl(name);
  fl.seekg( 0, ios::end );
  size_t len = fl.tellg();
  vector<char> ret(len);
  fl.seekg(0, ios::beg);
  if (len)
    fl.read(&ret[0], len);
  fl.close();
  return move(ret);
}

void SendImage(const string &strImageFile)
{
  using namespace boost::asio;
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  io_service io_service;
  ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
  ip::tcp::resolver::query query("192.168.1.13", "10555");
  ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
  ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
  connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);

  auto bytes = move(readFileBytes(strImageFile));
  write(socket, buffer(bytes), ec);

  streambuf respond;
  read(socket, respond, ec);
  string strOutput;
  strOutput = buffer_cast<const char*>(respond.data());
  respond.consume(strOutput.size());
  std::cout << "START OUTPUT: " << strOutput << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  SendImage("/tmagent/images/1.gif");
}
```